# I've number of latitude and longitude in array. I want to display multiple markers in Google Map

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-markers, swift4

I've number of latitude and longitude in array. I want to display multiple markers in Google Map. I am new in programming.

**** My Current Code****

import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

```
let mapView = GMSMapView()
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
let lattitudeary = ["28.5355","28.7041","29.9457","30.0869"]
let longitudeary = ["77.3910","77.1025","78.1642","78.2676"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    view = mapView

    var marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView



//    var coords = [[-33.86,151.20],[28.5355,77.1025],[29.9457,78.1642]]

    var coords = [[lattitudeary.count],[longitudeary.count]]

    for coord in coords {
        var marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(coord[0]), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(coord[1]))
        marker.map = mapView

    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your code and explain what you have done till now.

Comment: I've added my current code. Currently i'm getting,===> Fetal error: Index out of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First integrate Google Maps with the your app
[Google Maps iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start)

Then try to add marker to the map
[Adding a Map with a Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map-with-marker)

```
var marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
marker.title = "Sydney"
marker.snippet = "Australia"
marker.map = mapView
```

Finally use for loop to add multiple markers to the map. [Swift Control Flow](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID121)

```
var coords = [[-33.86,151.20],[-33.85,151.18],[-33.76,151.14]]
for coord in coords {
var marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coord[0], longitude: coord[1])
marker.map = mapView
}
```

Comment: Rather than just post code, it's better to provide additional explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I've updated my answer

Comment: It worked perfectly :) but when i am adding my latitude array and longitude array, I got this error ==> Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: let lattitudeary = ["28.5355","28.7041","29.9457","30.0869"],
  let longitudeary = ["77.3910","77.1025","78.1642","78.2676"]  ===> these ary my array for latitude and longitude.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this. I give you a simple solution. 
`let lattitudeary = ["28.5355","28.7041","29.9457","30.0869"] let longitudeary = ["77.3910","77.1025","78.1642","78.2676"] for i in 0..<lattitudeary.count { var marker = GMSMarker() marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lattitudeary[i])!, longitude: Double(longitudeary[i])!) marker.map = mapView }`
 !!the count of arrays must be equal and the coordinates in the array must match

Comment: It worked :) thanks alot. :)